# Jury: oath-takers or judges?

Tags: meaning, etymology, word-usage, history

Familiar as we may be with the modern jury, the right to judgment by peers is set forth in the Magna Carta:

*NO Freeman shall be taken or imprisoned, or be disseised of his Freehold, or Liberties, or free Customs, or be outlawed, or exiled, or any other wise destroyed; nor will We not pass upon him, nor [condemn him,] but by lawful judgment of his Peers, or by the Law of the Land.*

OED has this entry as the primary definition of *Jury*:

In legal use.

1. A company of persons (originally men) sworn to render a ‘verdict’ or true answer upon some question or questions officially submitted to them; in modern times, in a court of justice, usually upon evidence delivered to them touching the issue; but in the earliest times usually upon facts or matters within their own knowledge, for which reason they were summoned from the neighbourhood to which the question submitted to them related, or in which the person or persons lived as to whose conduct or death an ‘inquest’ or investigation was held.

https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/102169?rskey=arEQrO&result=1#eid

OED, and other dictionaries, cite the jurors' oath as the primary etymological source:

OED: *Old French jurée oath, juridical inquiry, inquest; medieval Latin jūrāta , noun from feminine past participle of iūrāre to swear*

But note the connotation of judging. Essentially, that is what "judgment by peers is all about.

Similarly in Merriam-Webster.com:
*Anglo-French juree, from feminine past participle of Old French jurer to swear, from Latin jurare, from jur-, jus law*

Etymologeek.com has:
*English word jury comes from Proto-Indo-European h₂yew-, Asturian xurar (To swear (promise).*

**Here's my question:** Since the jury's primary function was to adjudicate (fully, at first, and not only to ascertain the facts of the case), why relegate the primary etymolgy to the procedural aspect of the oath, rather than to the law, juris (as in: jurist, jurisdiction, jurisprudence etc.)?

Comment: You want to know why three dictionaries don't think jury comes from judging?

Comment: Are you asking if the history of the English word is from Old French 'juree' or borrowed directly from Late Latin 'jurare'? Of course these are all cognate and the OF 'juree' derived from Latin 'jurare'. Just so you understand, an etymology is not a assignation of a desired semantic explanation. Instead a linear connection has been shown through multiple documents over the years. Note that 'judge' is also obviously cognate but [a slightly different path](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=judge) 'jur-' - 'dicere' to say.

Comment: I think your question is not very clear. oath takers and judges?

Comment: Which is the primary source?

Comment: Is etymology just a question of linguistic archaeology, or can it strive to explore the semantic structure - the conceptual architecture of language? Sometimes we have no choice but to decide, as in transalation. Hebrew renders jury as *mushba'im*, those who were administered an oath. But we all use juries in contexts where there is no official oath, such a in talent shows and sporting competitions. Doesn't that reflect upon our conception of the semantics of jury as *jurists*?

Comment: @Mike It’s linguist archaeology. Semantic connections or intuitions may help guide our quest, but ultimately we are looking for the actual, documented development through history as evidenced by a series of documents. That tells us where th word originated, and has no obligation to accord with modern semantics, our intuitions on that count, and certainly not our desires. If “oath” is what the paper trail leads to, well, that’s that; we must satisfy ourselves with evidence, not conjecture. To do otherwise is to fall afoul [Etymological fallacy](http://en.Wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy)

Comment: If you want to go with "Hebrew renders jury as *mushba'im*," you have the passive right, but I'd translate it as those who are **sworn to**. So witnesses swear to the court and jury, and the jury receives oaths.

Comment: The OED says the original juries were called for many purposes, not all of which involved judging legal disputes or guilt. For instance to provide information to the King about something they had knowledge of, like a panel of experts, or to make other decisions. Even today an American Grand Jury isn't exactly there to determine the outcome of a case. So it's plausible that their name comes from their constitution, not from judging.